# Add method-call to setter (serialize)

Tags: ruby, serialization

I have several classes that are serialized to a file with YAML. In order to serialize it when an attribute changes, I've implement custom setters for each of them:

```
def serialize
  File.open(@inipath, 'w') do |file|
    file << YAML.dump(self)
  end
end

def numbering=(value)
  @numbering = value
  serialize
end

def savepath=(value)
  @savepath = value
  serialize
end

def active=(value)
  @active = value
  serialize
end

...
```

Can this be done without the repetition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use a bit of metaprogramming secret sauce here.

Here's the sauce:

```
module OptInSerialization
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def serialize_on_changes_in(*names)
      names.each do |name|
        alias_method "old_#{name}=", "#{name}="

        define_method "#{name}=" do |val|
          send("old_#{name}=", val)
          serialize
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's how you use it:

```
class Foo
  include OptInSerialization

  attr_accessor :hello, :there

  serialize_on_changes_in :hello

  def serialize
    puts 'serialized'
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.hello = '1234' # >> serialized
f.there = 'asdf'
```

Note that here serialization is not triggered by assigning to `there`, because you didn't specify it.

<sub>Disclaimer: This MP magic may be way above your current level, so don't use it, if you don't understand it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here ClassName would be name of the Model and column_names will give you all the columns of that model.

```
ClassName.column_names.each do |type|
    define_method("#{type}=(value)") do
      eval"@#{type}"
      instance_variable_set("@#{type}",value )
      serialize
    end


def column_names
  ['numbering','savepath']
end
```

Comment: You could create a method column_names which would return whatever setters you want.